# Error on store emoticons on MySQL Table even with utf8mb4 charset

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to allow user to add emoticons to your personal message.

All posts tells me to change default charset, but I already changed my collation and charset to utf8mb4.

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE message message VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

but when I try:

```
UPDATE mytable SET message = '' WHERE (`id` = '1');
```

I still getting the fallowing error:

> Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x97\xF0\x9F...'

What am I still missing?

I'm running all these commands on MySQL Workbench connect to a MySQL 5.7 server.

I Created my database using Docker using Docker-compose.

```
my-db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci --max-allowed-packet=1073741824
```

Also I got the fallowing results from mysql variables.

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server    utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5fRGmn7o8dCqdjUXwULVv7/0). What version of MySQL Workbench are you using?.

Comment: I ran exactaly the commands above. I've created the server with Docker